# Update Persisted Model in Background Thread

Tags: swift-data, swift-concurrency

Every time the user needs to compute the data of a persisted item, task that is expensive, I show a computing text while in background thread I compute the data and when is ready I show it to the user.

The app works as expected but

1. I am not really sure 100% that my approach is the most efficient
2. one warning appears:

> Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'ItemEditView' in a `@Sendable` closure.
> Consider making struct 'ItemEditView' conform to the 'Sendable' protocol

```swift
struct ItemEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    let item: Item
    @State private var text = "Computing..."
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(text)
        }
        .task{
            Task.detached{
                do {
                    let dataManager = DataManager(modelContainer: modelContext.container) //warning here!
                    try await dataManager.computeData(for: item.id)
                    text = String(item.data!)
                    // Not sure if saving the main context is also needed
                    try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
@ModelActor
actor DataManager{
    
    func computeData(for itemID: PersistentIdentifier) async throws {
        let item = modelContext.model(for: itemID) as! Item
        item.data = expensiveWork()
        try modelContext.save()
    }
}
```

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    var data: Double?
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(item.name)")
                        if let data = item.data{
                            Text("Data: \(data)")
                        }
                        NavigationLink("Compute Data"){
                            ItemEditView(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(name: "Name\(items.count)")
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```swift
extension DataManager {
    private func expensiveWork() -> Double {
        for i in 0..<100_000 {
            print("\(i)")
        }
        return .random(in: 0...100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Task.detached` inside a `.task`?

Comment: If I remove `Task.detached`  runs on main thread and blocks the UI

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but I don't get any warning (and I don't experience any issues with UI being blocked but my called function obviously doesn't do the same type of work)

Comment: https://github.com/quaternionboy/LifeKPIs-Playground

Comment: Maybe I get the warning because I set `Strict Concurrency Checking` project setting to `Complete`.

Comment: Edited post to add function simulating expensive work

Comment: Good catch about the concurrency testing, I am running this in my SwiftData test project and I never considered changing that setting. When I set it to Complete I get the same warning.

Comment: I believe it's the print statement inside the loop that is giving you issues with a frozen UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a detached Task without getting any warnings about `Sendable` from the compiler we need to declare any local variables before the Task closure rather than inside, that way we won't capture `self`.

So we move the declaration of `dataManager` and we also need to declare a variable for model id or we get the same warning

```
.task {
    let dataManager = DataManager(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
    let id = model.persistentModelID
    //...
}
```

And for the same reason we can't update `text` inside the closure but we can fix that by running the task using `await` and assign `text` afterwards

```
.task {
    let dataManager = DataManager(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
    let id = model.persistentModelID
    let _ = await Task.detached {
        do {
            try await dataManager.computeData(for: id)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.result

    text = String(model.doubleValue)
}
```

*(The code is from my test project so some properties and functions aren't named exactly the same but the logic and flow should match.)*

If you want to run this every time a new object is shown in the view I would recommend using `task(id:)` instead of `task`

```
.task(id: model.id) { ... }
```

I am not convinced you need to use `Task.detached` at all so here is my version without it

```
.task(id: model.id) {
    let dataManager = DataManager(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
    do {
        try await dataManager.computeData(for: model.id)
        text = String(model.doubleValue)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And I simulated a long operation by using `try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))` rather than a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, `Task.detached` is not necessary